# Accessing my samsung f480T through Nautilus

Tags: storage, phone, samsung

Ubuntu isn't detecting my samsung f480T when I plug it in. After a bit of Googling, I found nothing. Do Samsung phones require a driver to be installed to work?

Comment: What were you expecting it to do?

Comment: Add & remove files (Mainly music) like a mass storage device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phone probably has a "USB storage device mode" (or something similar) that will allow it to act like a USB hard drive when connected to a computer.